# How to add a Filter By dropdown maenu in a slite3 table header

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, cs50

i am developing a web app in python using flask and a sqlite3 database. It is a web app for anonymous bullyng reports in schools.
In a route called tablatestigos i want to display a table with the information of the database. The headers of the table are "Escuela", "Curso", "Victima" and "Descripcion del hecho" but i want to make that "Curso" header to be a dropdown menu (like a Filter By header) and if you select for example the course 5A, it should display ONLY the table rows of that course. 
I managed to create the table correctly and add that dropdown menu with all the courses in the header in html but i don't know how to connect it properly to the database so when i click in a certain "curso" it shows me only the rows for it.
I don't want the webpage to refresh everytime a course is selected, i want it to happen dinamically.

This is my python and flask code:

```
@app.route("/tablatestigos", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def tablatestigos():
    escuela = session["user_id"]
    hechos = db.execute("SELECT * FROM testigos WHERE escuela = :escuela", escuela=session["user_id"])
    if not hechos:
        return apology("No se han recibido reportes aún.")
    return render_template("tablatestigos.html", hechos=hechos)
```

Here is my html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Reportes de Testigos
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Escuela</th>
                <th>Curso</th>
                <th>Victima</th>
                <th>Descripción del hecho</th>
                <th>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Todos
                      <span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" name="curso">
                        {% for hecho in hechos %}
                        <li><a href="#">{{ hecho.curso }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

    {% for hecho in hechos %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ hecho.escuela }}</td>
                    <td>{{ hecho.curso }}</td>
                    <td>{{ hecho.victima }}</td>
                    <td>{{ hecho.hecho }}</td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Sorry if this is a very noob question but i am new to coding and this is my first web app project i am developing.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to look into AJAX to update the results based on the selection from a dropdown. It's simple enough, but it is not a noob question. Have you used AJAX before?

Comment: I would suggest using flask-admin for this.

Comment: I have heard of ajax that is used to make changes in website so they happen dinamically, i am doing cs50 and they show ajax but very briefly so i don't know how to make this change with ajax. What is your idea?